# Python: replace columns using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, database, dictionary, replace

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df:
date        price region        currency
2022-01-01  1     NorthAmerica  UnitedStatesDollar
2022-01-01  1.28  NorthAmerica  CanadianDollar
2022-01-01  1.42  Oceania       AustralianDollar
2022-01-02  1     NorthAmerica  UnitedStatesDollar
2022-01-02  1.29  NorthAmerica  CanadianDollar
2022-01-02  1.41  Oceania       AustralianDollar
```

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
currency_dict = [
  {
    'symbol': 'USD',
    'region': 'NorthAmerica',
    'currency': 'UnitedStatesDollar',
  },
  {
    'symbol': 'CAD',
    'region': 'NorthAmerica',
    'currency': 'CanadianDollar',
  },
  {
    'symbol': 'AUD',
    'region': 'Oceania',
    'currency': 'AustralianDollar',
  },
];
```

I want to use the dictionary to get the following DataFrame:

```
df:
date        price  symbol
2022-01-01  1      USD
2022-01-01  1.28   CAD
2022-01-01  1.42   AUD
2022-01-02  1      USD
2022-01-02  1.29   CAD
2022-01-02  1.41   AUD
```

I have tried `df.replace(currency_dict, inplace=True)` but I am not sure how that would work with replacing two columns.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: This is a list of dictionaries! Thanks for all the comments

Comment: Just to make it clear (in case you hadn't realized it yet) but your currency_dict is not a dictionary  - but a list of dictionaries (in which each dictionary in the list can be said to represent a row of values in a dataframe, if that is where you are going with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example:

```
df_currency = pd.DataFrame(currency_dict) # currency_dict actually a list of dict!!
result = pd.merge(df, df_currency)[['date', 'price', 'symbol']]
```

References:

https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it was referred to as a list of dicts. Thanks for the explanation too!

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `.merge()` ([pandas.DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)): works like an SQL-join operation and even on multiple columns as keys

*your example (I am way too lazy to reproduce it entirely)*

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
[{'price': 1, 'region': 'NorthAmerica', 'currency': 'UnitedStatesDollar'},
{'price': 1.28, 'region': 'NorthAmerica', 'currency': 'CanadianDollar'},
{'price': 1.42, 'region': 'Oceania', 'currency': 'AustralianDollar'},
{'price': 1, 'region': 'NorthAmerica', 'currency': 'UnitedStatesDollar'},
])

currency_dict = [
  {
    'symbol': 'USD',
    'region': 'NorthAmerica',
    'currency': 'UnitedStatesDollar',
  },
  {
    'symbol': 'CAD',
    'region': 'NorthAmerica',
    'currency': 'CanadianDollar',
  },
  {
    'symbol': 'AUD',
    'region': 'Oceania',
    'currency': 'AustralianDollar',
  },
]
```

*merge*

```py
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(currency_dict), on=['currency', 'region'])
```

**output**

|  | price | region | currency | symbol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.00 | NorthAmerica | UnitedStatesDollar | USD |
| 1 | 1.00 | NorthAmerica | UnitedStatesDollar | USD |
| 2 | 1.28 | NorthAmerica | CanadianDollar | CAD |
| 3 | 1.42 | Oceania | AustralianDollar | AUD |

Comment: May I ask how you format the output so nicely?

Comment: never mind - I got it :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables

Comment: Ah sry @topsail xD You can pretty much use all [markdown commands](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/) here =)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(currency_dict)
df["symbol"] = df["currency"].map(df2.set_index("currency")["symbol"])

print(df[["date", "price", "symbol"]])
```

Prints:

```
         date  price symbol
0  2022-01-01   1.00    USD
1  2022-01-01   1.28    CAD
2  2022-01-01   1.42    AUD
3  2022-01-02   1.00    USD
4  2022-01-02   1.29    CAD
5  2022-01-02   1.41    AUD
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with replace. As @topsail mentioned in the comment your dictionary is actually a list of dictionaries so the first step is to construct a dictionary that will do the job.
The we do replace on the currency column. As a last step we rename the column.

```
conv_dict={}
#consturcting dict to use with replace
for item in currency_dict:
    conv_dict[item["currency"]]=item["symbol"]
    
    
df["currency"]=df["currency"].replace(conv_dict)
df=df.rename({"currency":"symbol"})

df=df.loc[:,["date","price","currency"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas.apply is always a good idea when you try to perform a function on a whole column

```
def symbol(currency):
    for i in range(3):
        if currency_dict[i]['currency'] == currency:
            return currency_dict[i]['symbol']

df['symbol'] = df.currency.apply(symbol)
```